# Android distorted ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with let's say 30 items.

For the items, I'm using a custom adapter, which I store in an instance variable of the containing activity.

Now I want to cache the content (my list with model objects) in some cases. It means if I resume the activity nothing has to change.

If the model is cached I assume I don't need to redraw the view because nothing has changed.

Without caching I call this each time, in onResume:

```
myAdapter.setMyData(new ArrayList<MyType>());
myAdapter.setFoo(new Foo());
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And that works, the list is displayed well.

But when I don't call that (besides of the very first time this activity is resumed)  (because I'm using the cache), the ListView looks strange. While normally ~ 7 items fit in the screen, now I get only ~ 2 with a very long space in between. And the assets inside the items also a bit shifted. Scrolling down fixes it, the following items look normally, and if I scroll back up everything looks fine.

Why is this?

Edit: The key of the issue is

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If I call that each time in onResume the list is displayed correctly. But I don't understand why I have to do it, because my data set didn't change.

Comment: How do you cache? Do you use some kind of weakreference or static data?

Comment: It's a list of domain objects which is stored in another (singleton) instance. The domain data itself is correct. But the list looks distorted, like the layout is messed up (don't see any reason like big pictures or similar)

Comment: Show me the code or I'm out of ideas :)

Comment: Oh no... at least not now, it's a bit complex. But I'll check myself if there's a quirk somewhere which makes the list change, or something else... in a while. For now I'm ok letting notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume()...